# How to find the average (in days) between dates (datetime) in a field in SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008

My data has two fields. One is the membership id and the other one is the call dates that members have made throughout the years. I'm interested to find the average days in between calls per member.  I have only one field (column)for my dates.

```
MembershipId    CallDates
123             01/01/2014
123             01/06/2014
123             01/15/2014
234             01/01/2014
234             01/15/2014
345             01/06/2014
456             01/06/2014
```

My query:

```
WITH OrderDates AS 
  ( 
    SELECT 
        SC_CALL_MBR_ID, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by SC_CALL_MBR_ID ORDER BY SC_DT DESC) AS RowNumber, 
        SC_DT 
    FROM [D3Reporting].[dbo].[ASC_ARCH_CALL] 
    WHERE sc_dt >'2015-06-17 00:00:00.0000000'
  ) 

SELECT 
    tab1.SC_CALL_MBR_ID, 
    avg(DATEDIFF(DD, tab2.SC_DT ,tab1.SC_DT)) AS 'AverageDate' 
FROM 
    OrderDates tab1 
     LEFT JOIN 
    OrderDates tab2 ON 
        tab2.RowNumber = tab1.RowNumber + 1 
GROUP BY tab1.SC_CALL_MBR_ID
```

Comment: WITH OrderDates AS (
    SELECT   SC_CALL_MBR_ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by  SC_CALL_MBR_ID ORDER BY SC_DT DESC) AS RowNumber,
        SC_DT
    FROM [D3Reporting].[dbo].[ASC_ARCH_CALL] where sc_dt >'2015-06-17 00:00:00.0000000')
SELECT tab1.SC_CALL_MBR_ID,   
     avg(DATEDIFF(DD, tab2.SC_DT ,tab1.SC_DT)) AS 'AverageDate'
FROM OrderDates tab1
LEFT JOIN OrderDates tab2 
    ON tab2.RowNumber = tab1.RowNumber + 1
    group by  tab1.SC_CALL_MBR_ID

Comment: sorry I'm new to both sql and this site so I don't know how to format the code nicely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is by a self-join to get the prior date, calculate the differences between the call dates, and then compute the average.  See the first query below.

The question was tagged as SQL Server 2008, so you cannot use LAG and LEAD.  I included another example below that uses LAG for those who are using a more recent version.

```
declare @Membership table
(
    id int,
    calldate datetime
)

-- generate some test data    
insert into @Membership
select 1, '1/1/2015'
union all select 1, '1/2/2015'
union all select 1, '1/5/2015'
union all select 1, '2/1/2015 8:00 AM' -- test using a time value
union all select 1, '2/1/2015 9:00 AM'
union all select 2, '1/1/2015'
union all select 2, '1/14/2015'
union all select 2, '2/14/2015'


-- This method should work on older SQL Server versions
-- Number the membership/call date rows.
;with CallTimesOrdered (num, id, calldate) as
(
select
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by calldate),
    id,
    calldate
    from @Membership
),
-- Join the numbered rows back to each other.
AvgCallTimes (id, timespan) as
(
    select
        CurrentDate.id,
        datediff(d, PriorDate.calldate, CurrentDate.calldate)
    from CallTimesOrdered CurrentDate
    inner join CallTimesOrdered PriorDate
        on PriorDate.num = CurrentDate.num - 1
        and PriorDate.id = CurrentDate.id
)
-- Compute the average days between calls by membership ID.
select id, avg(timespan) as AvgTimeBetweenCalls
from AvgCallTimes
group by id

-- This version works with SQL 2012 and higher versions.
-- It uses LAG function.
-- First, calculate the difference in days between the current and the prior dates.
;with AvgCallTimes (id, avgtimespan) as
(
select
    id,
    datediff(d, lag(calldate, 1, null) over (partition by id order by calldate), calldate)
from @Membership
)
-- Calculate the average time span in days by membership ID.
select id, avg(avgtimespan) as AvgTimeBetweenCalls
from AvgCallTimes
group by id
```

In both cases using the test data below, I get the following results:

```
ID  AvgTimeBetweenCalls
1   7
2   22
```

Answer (score 0):

Take distinct call date per member and then take Avg out of that result.

```
Select   t.MemberId
        ,Avg(CallDate) As CallPerMember
From    (
            Select   Distinct
                     MemberId
                    ,CallDate
            From    Membership As m With (Nolock)
        ) As t
Group By t.MemberId
```

Comment: I like Mihir Shah's answer but would suggest you consider one more factor.   If a person became a member and then for many months or years made no calls, then made several in a short time, then no more calls again for many months or years, that user should rightly have a less dense average call rate from someone who became a member then very quickly made several calls.   So, consider using unions in the subquery to add a record equal to the membership join date, and another for the current date.   This will take into account total membership time.